# Arm template validation fails through Azure Devops release, works from powershell and test-AzResourceGroupDeployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template

I have a release setup that I'm trying get out through Azure Devops release pipelines.  This is based on another release that I've cloned and works fine.

The issue is that the template is failing a validation check and not going any further.  Strange thing is i'm able to check the syntax successfully with new-AzResourceGroupDeployment and test-AzResourceGroupDeployment.  It reports no errors and has been deploying fine.

Using Azure Devops release the error coming back is:

```
2020-02-26T12:26:16.2632844Z ==============================================================================
2020-02-26T12:26:16.2633634Z Task         : ARM template deployment
2020-02-26T12:26:16.2634204Z Description  : Deploy an Azure Resource Manager (ARM) template to all the deployment scopes
2020-02-26T12:26:16.2634534Z Version      : 3.1.19
2020-02-26T12:26:16.2634945Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-02-26T12:26:16.2635504Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment
2020-02-26T12:26:16.2635948Z ==============================================================================
2020-02-26T12:26:16.8677026Z ARM Service Conection deployment scope - Subscription
2020-02-26T12:26:16.8760315Z Checking if the following resource group exists: myResourceGroup.
2020-02-26T12:26:17.2234188Z Resource group exists: true.
2020-02-26T12:26:17.2259290Z Creating deployment parameters.
2020-02-26T12:26:17.2558066Z The detected encoding for file 'd:\a\r1\a\_Azure-Infrastructure\myResourceGroup\deployment\azuredeploy.json' is 'utf-8'
2020-02-26T12:26:17.2561303Z The detected encoding for file 'd:\a\r1\a\_Azure-Infrastructure\myResourceGroup\deployment\param.dev.json' is 'utf-8'
2020-02-26T12:26:17.5304032Z Starting template validation.
2020-02-26T12:26:17.5304834Z Deployment name is Release-vstfs:///ReleaseManagement/Release/95
2020-02-26T12:26:17.5877973Z ##[warning]Validation errors were found in the Azure Resource Manager template. This can potentially cause template deployment to fail. Template validation failed. Error: {"message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/mySubscription/resourcegroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/Release-vstfs:/ReleaseManagement/Release/95/validate?api-version=2017-05-10'."}.. Please follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-syntax
2020-02-26T12:26:17.5890527Z Starting Deployment.
2020-02-26T12:26:17.5891348Z Deployment name is Release-vstfs:///ReleaseManagement/Release/95
2020-02-26T12:26:17.6289831Z There were errors in your deployment. Error code: undefined.
2020-02-26T12:26:17.6291819Z ##[error][object Object]
2020-02-26T12:26:17.6295387Z ##[error]Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.
2020-02-26T12:26:17.6399260Z ##[section]Finishing: ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope
```

​Looking the log above, I'm not sure if it's failing on the validation errors or on the error near the end with a undefined error code.

The task is from another subscription and it's listed in the Azure Resource Manager connection on the task and also lists the subscription and the resource groups in the subscription.

Anyone any ideas on how I can get this working or where to start troubleshooting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your deployment name is:

```
Release-vstfs:/ReleaseManagement/Release/95
```

fairly certain that's not allowed (`/`). so you need to set your deployment name to something reasonable.

ps. `:` might not be allowed as well

Comment: Brilliant, that's the one.  Working now!  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the Activity Log in [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_ActivityLog/ActivityLogBlade)?

All deployment attempts are logged here. Look in particular at the JSON pane, often the real issue is only displayed here.

Otherwise, if it doesn't reach Azure, can you double check the service connection in Azure DevOps? (in particular the related user permission in Azure)

Comment: It's not even hitting the azure portal and showing up as a deployment